# Regular expression for finding a sub-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string-matching, python-regex

I am trying to find all occurances of a sub-string using regular expression. The sub-string is composed of three parts, starts with one or more 'A', followed by one or more 'N' and ended with one or more 'A'. Let a string *'AAANAANABNA'* and if I parse the string I should get two sub-strings *'AAANAA'* and *'AANA'* as the output. So, I have tried the below code.

```
import regex as re
reg_a='A+N+A+'
s='AAANAANABNA'
sub_str=re.findall(reg_a,s,overlapped=True)
print(sub_str)
```

And, I am getting the below output,

```
['AAANAA', 'AANAA', 'ANAA', 'AANA', 'ANA']
```

But, I want the output as,

```
['AAANAA', 'AANA']
```

That is, the trailing A's of the first match should be the leading A's of the next match.
How can I get that, any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure there are no `A` on the left:

```
>>> reg_a='(?<!A)A+N+A+'
>>> print( re.findall(reg_a,s,overlapped=True) )
['AAANAA', 'AANA']
```

The `(?<!A)A+N+A+` matches

- `(?<!A)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with `A`
- `A+` - one or more `A`s
- `N+` - one or more `N`s
- `A+` - one or more `A`s

Note you may use `re` to get the matches, too:

```
>>> import re
>>> re_a = r'(?=(?<!A)(A+N+A+))'
>>> print( re.findall(re_a, s) )
['AAANAA', 'AANA']
```

Comment: I never used the `overlapped=True`, learned something new. ++

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a negative lookbehind with a capturing group inside a positive lookahead without the overlapped. re.findall will return the value of the capturing group.

```
(?=(?<!A)(A+N+A+))
```

- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?<!A)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the left is not A
  - `(A+N+A+)` Match your pattern
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/73TVh2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hP8fhJ)

```
import re
s = "AAANAANABNA"
pattern = r"(?=(?<!A)(A+N+A+))"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['AAANAA', 'AANA']
```

Or as suggested by [@anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), separate the lookbehind from the lookahead:

```
(?<!A)(?=(A+N+A+))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OKWl5z/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/GHucaG)

Comment: I think this has a slight edge over the 3rd party regex? Upvoted both, I quite like the question too =)

Comment: I can't really tell, did you have a pattern in mind using the regex pypi module?

Comment: `(?<!A)(?=(A+N+A+))` might be a bit faster with same matches

Comment: @Thefourthbird, thank you for sharing nice code and demo cheers

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler way of achieving this with `re` module. We just need a lookahead for 1+ trailing `A`s and have to use use 2 capture groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'AAANAANABNA'
>>> [''.join(x) for x in re.findall(r'(A+N+)(?=(A+))', s)]
['AAANAA', 'AANA']
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/llByTo/2)

Comment: Nice find joining the groups ++